# uiview doesn't show in app delegate

Tags: iphone, uiview, ipad, uiwindow

When I execute the code below in the simulator I expect to see red fill the screen, but instead it's all black, why?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  UIView * myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[window bounds]];
  [myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
  [window addSubview:myView];
  [window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```

If I add initialization of window, that doesn't help:

```
window = [[[UIWindow alloc] init] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

My troubles begun when after creating a Window-based Universal project in Xcode I decided to delete the iPad/iPhone xib files and the iPhone/iPad app delegate files that were automatically created in the project, and instead have a single app delegate with a view controller that builds the view programmatically based on the device.  Now I can't seem to display a simple view I create in the app delegate.

Edit: I removed adding a view, and now set the background color of the window to red.  That doesn't help, but if I go to desktop in the simulator and reopen the running app I get now a red screen.  Again, I'm puzzled as to why I don't see red the first time I launch the app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are the steps to setup a non-InterfaceBuilder (.xib) Universal iOS project.

1. Delete all associations to the .xib files in your property list for the application.
   [image: Delete the .xib file references from your application plist]
2. Delete all the .xib files from the project
3. (Optional) Create a common Application Delegate class, and then delete the AppDelegate_iPad.* and the AppDelegate_iPhone.* files. (Copy paste any code from the existing files before deleting)
4. Change your main.m file to name the application delegate. I chose to modify and use the AppDelegate_iPhone for example purposes. See the documentation: [UIApplication Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIApplicationMain)

   // main.m
   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

   ```
   NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
   // Start an iPhone/iPad App using a .xib file (Defaults set in .plist)
   //int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);

   // Start the iPhone/iPad App programmatically
   // Set the 3rd argument to nil, to use the default UIApplication
   // Set the 4th argument to the string name of your AppDelegate class
   int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate_iPhone");

   [pool release];
   return retVal;
   ```

   }
5. Update your application delegate code.

   // AppDelegate_iPhone.m
       - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

   ```
       // Override point for customization after application launch.
       NSLog(@"Launch my application iphone");

       // Create the window, it's not created without a nib
       window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; 

       // Create a subview that is red
       UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[window bounds]];
       [myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

       // Add the subview and release the memory, sicne the window owns it now
       [self.window addSubview:myView];
       [myView release]; 

       [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

       return YES;
   }
   ```

Comment: This is a great answer and outlines the steps that I took but in better detail.  Turns out my fault was in initializing UIWindow twice (see above).  Now all works.  Thanks for your excellent answer.

Comment: You're welcome, I found this to be frustrating when I first started since there are a number of steps and places to edit project settings/code. I'm not sure why, but on my end the code isn't formatted correctly even though I attempted to mark it as code.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run your code and it worked for me. I got en empty view that was coloured red. Have you tried adding breakpoints and checking that your code actually gets executed? Otherwise the only thing I can come up with is that it is something with your UIWindow.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was, I initialized the window incorrectly, I did a double init like so: [[[UIWindow alloc] init] initWithFrame:bounds].  Once I removed the first init I had it working.  I spent over 6 hours on this LOL.  Thanks!

Comment: sometimes you just have to leave the keyboard for a while and come back later. Glad to hear that you solved it.