# Show a UIView from the AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, delegates

I am implementing a login system into my existing app. I have already set up settings so that the user can turn on password protection and set their password.

In the

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

method I detect whether or not the user has password protection enabled. If they do I would like to log them in - before they can access the app. At the moment it works by calling an alert view with a single text field.

Although this works, you can still see the app in the background which is undesired.

Is it possible to (in the AppDelegate) create a UIView with a black opacity background, and show it on top of the current window. I have tried many solutions ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415807/uiview-doesnt-show-in-app-delegate)) but cannot get it working.

FOR NOTE: I am using ARC and Storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

Create UiWindow:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
```

Synthesize it:

```
@synthesize window = _window;
```

In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions add:

```
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [self.window addSubview:view];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not present a modal view? Create the view in your storyboard don't connect it create an instance and then use

`[self presentViewController:/*yourviewController*/ animated:yes/no completion:^{}]`